# How should I handle each of Acrid's damage over time variants?

Tags: risk-of-rain-2

Acrid has access to two damage over time effects. One is called Poison, and the other is called Blight. What should I do to get the most optimal use out of them? Does one scale better than the other? How should I play around each of them respectively?